# How do you create a simple user validation java filter?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, servlet-filters

Let's say that I have four jsps: signInInfo.jsp, signIn.jsp, home.jsp, and about.jsp.  I don't want users to be able to see the home.jsp or about.jsp until they are signed in.  It is fine if they view signInInfo.jsp and signIn.jsp before signing in.  If a user that has not signed in tries to access either home or about, they should be redirected to signIn.jsp.  Would someone please show me how to implement this simple filter.  It has proved more challenging than I originally expected.  Thank you.

Comment: This is already covered in [StackOverflow Servlet-Filters wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: If you are using tomcat that should help http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luiggi said, This is already covered in [StackOverflow Servlet-Filters wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).  It is a great article for those who are looking for easy filter implementation.